# Request timeout , Connection has been reset error while rendering jsp page

Tags: java, html

I have a jsp page which is used to generate multipart data (an xls).
I am not getting any data at this jsp page but when i tried to print the data in log, I can see that all the records fetched.

How is the request getting processed.

`Request ---(goes to)---> Webservlet ---(delegate to handler)---> Java Class(ReportHandler.java)`

Now we call a method of `ReportHandler.runReport()` which is responsible to get data from database. This method takes a long time (almost 12 min) to fetch the records.
Once we get the data in result set, we pass it to jsp page and using the result set to generate report.

`1> while(rs.next()) {system.out.println("<tr><td>"+partnerId+"</td></tr>")}`

I can see the partnerId - it is getting printed on console.
But the jsp is not rendering the data on the browser. After 12-14 min, the browser show an error message (without status code), request times out and connection was reset.

Now my question is if the connection was timed out at server then data would not be getting printed on console and if the connection is getting timed out at client end then how to fix it, I tried to fix the time out at client end by setting `network.http.connection.timeout` property to long but no effect.

`2> I am using out.print(<table><tr><td>"+rs.getInt(partnerId)+"</td></tr></table>")`

to generate report but it is not generating any data on jsp though the `data(out.flush())` is forcefully flushed.
I am sure we are getting data at jsp page but it is not rendering because `System.out.println()` above is printing records in while loop.

Please help as it has been a long since I am searching for a solution but could not get any clue to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't shrink the backend time to something reasonable (less than 5-10 seconds, it depends on the kind of audience) you'd better change your pattern. If it makes sense, you could schedule the creation of the document at specified time (for example with Quartz). Otherwise you'll need some kind of server notification. Since long polling is a waste of resources and a dedicated comet server doesn't make sense only for this thing, I suggest the old Javascript polling. Basically you have a script that every `X` seconds check if the document is ready. You'll modify the server-side script to follow this pattern by implementing two different scripts. One does the actual work, while the other manage a table of background processes and their states, and is notified by the other script. This is the implementation in pseudo code

```
//~client
every 30 seconds check /document?id=12345 {
  if (ready) {
     display URL for download
     break
  } else {
     display loading.gif
  }
}

//~server (worker) not reachable by public URL, it's a background thread
notify: processing document with id #1234
.... do processing ....
notify: finished document with id #1234

//~server (notifier) has a URL like /document?id=1234
if (#1234 isReady)
   output #1234.URL
else
   output "processing..."
```